# How to make Log4j Custom Patterns

Tags: java, log4j2

Is there some way I can set up my logging in a way such that when it's putting data into my database through the appender that I can have a custom pattern that is storing some value like an id? Like for example I want to be able to do something like

`<Column name="special_id" pattern="%something" />`

I was looking through the api and I couldn't find anything like this.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is an easy documented way to do that. The pattern is quite strict. However, there are %X and %x which are supposed to be used for custom user defined data.